# How can I get the name of the files webpack outputs for the JS and the CSS?

Tags: webpack

After completing its various subprocesses resulting in a bundled JS file and a bundled CSS file, I need to get those filenames and manually perform a final operation with them in my build process. How can I modify my webpack.config.js to get access to those final filenames (e.g. `bundle-9aef5a96e.en-US.js`)?

I need something akin to:

```
finalOperation: (js, css) => { /* code using js filename and css filename */ }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can use a Webpack [compiler hook](https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/#done) for the `done` phase to enqueue your final build operation. The `done` hook gets executed when the compilation has completed and receives a `stats` parameter in its callback (see [Link](https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/#done)).

From `stats` you can grab output files emitted from the compilation via the `assets` which takes output file name as key and maps it to an [asset object](https://webpack.js.org/api/stats/#asset-objects). E.g.

```
Object.keys(stats.compilation.assets) // emitted file names, what you want
Object.values(stats.compilation.assets) // details about each asset
```

As an alternative you could retrieve all files via traversing your chunks:

```
stats.compilation.chunks.map(c => c.files)
```

More info on the stats object is [here](https://webpack.js.org/api/stats/). Add code like this as a plugin in your webpack.config.js:

```
plugins: [
  // ...
  {
    apply: compiler => {
      compiler.hooks.done.tap("My-FinalizePlugin", stats => {
        // your finalize build step
        console.log(stats.compilation.chunks.map(c => c.files))
        console.log(Object.keys(stats.compilation.assets))
      })
    }
  }
]
```

Hope, that gets the job done.

Comment: Hey, sorry, took me 10 months to come back to this-- got totally diverted from the work for a long time. Thank you for this really detailed and complete response, it's super helpful, especially since webpack's docs are honestly quite poor. I haven't tried it yet, but I'm just wondering what the deal is with the `apply` property on the object literal-- where is it documented that you should do it this way? I totally believe you, I just am curious if it's mentioned in the documentation anywhere. I haven't been able to find it yet.

Comment: No worries. I don't remember my exact source though (-: . `apply` is just, how [Webpack plugins](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/plugins/#anatomy) work, see also the provided links in the answer.